# How to add Apache Cordova in Visual Studio 2015 ASP.NET MVC project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, hybrid-mobile-app, visual-studio-cordova, multi-device-hybrid-apps

I want to create a project for multiple target systems, a web application and a hybrid mobile app using a common ASP.NET back-end.
As far I know it's possible to create now a hybrid mobile app using the Apache Cordova Apps template in Visual Studio 2015. I'm also familiar with ASP.NET MVC.
Is it possible to add Apache Cordova and Angular to an ASP.NET MVC project to enable also mobile views, so it can be also tested and deployed to any mobile platforms? (I'd prefer to use ASP.NET MVC instead of Web API)

If no, is it possible to extend the Apache Cordova Apps project with  ASP.NET Web Application for back-end to reach the same goals?

Are any samples available, which demonstrate the project structure for?

Answer (score 1):

You should open a different Cordova project, MVC is server side and cordova is client side.  I suggest you try the ionic template or the onsen ui.
You can run this code on a browser no worries.
check this out: http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tutorial-ionic/

Answer (score 1):

You might want to read this article on hosted apps for more info:
http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/create-a-hosted-app/

Comment: is this still around? 404 on the link above