# How to use ASP.NET Web pages on Cordova Project

Tags: javascript, c#, android, asp.net, cordova

I looked into Apache Cordova and I figured it would be a great place to start mobile development for Android/iOS phones. According to the Cordova website, it allows developers to develop mobile apps using HTML, CSS,and JavaScript. My plan is to add ASP.NET web pages onto the Cordova project so I can use C# for backened development. I've been google searching ways to add ASP files to Cordova but I didn't find it helpful. So here are my questions.

Is there a way to add ASP files to a Cordova project, or to convert an ASP project into Cordova? Any answer for this question is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: There's a similar question on StackOverflow with a couple answers (But none accepted), that might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34029859/how-to-add-apache-cordova-in-visual-studio-2015-asp-net-mvc-project

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think this is possible without heavily extending Cordova itself. Out-of-the-box, Apache doesn't even support ASP.Net.

Answer (score 0):

Try using InAppBrowser Cordova plugin which allow you to show third party web pages.